# Storing images locally, from JSON. How to?

Tags: c#, json, image, windows-phone-8, local-storage

Wonder if you can help me out over here...

I retrieved some data from an API and I have it in a list, now, after deserializing it...

Now, this data has some images I need to place into a `gridview` in a different page and since I was asked to save the data locally (and check for updates once in a while) I wonder what do I have to do to:

1. Make sure I get the picture (and not only the name)
2. Save it to a local storage (with its id) to make, later one, the
   Data Binding resource...

Here´s what I have:

```
public class GetFromJson
{

    private Medio medio = new Medio();
    public async void GetFullResponse(string address)
    {
        try
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();

            var uri = new Uri(address);
            var Response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
            var statusCode = Response.StatusCode;

            Response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            var ResponseText = await Response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            string myJson = ResponseText;

            medio.deserializeAndConvert(myJson);

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Then, to **deserialize** the data:

```
public class Medio
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string img { get; set; }
    public string medios_id { get; set; }

    public void deserializeAndConvert(string aaa)
    {
        JObject myGeneral = JObject.Parse(aaa);
        IList<JToken> results = myGeneral["resp"]["medios"].Children().ToList();

        IList<Medio> searchResults = new List<Medio>();
        foreach (JToken result in results)
        {
            Medio searchResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Medio>(result.ToString());
            searchResults.Add(searchResult);
            Debug.WriteLine(searchResults);

        }


        Debug.WriteLine(searchResults.Count);
        GlobalVariables.Medios = searchResults;
    }
}
```

With that I get the piece of data I need to work with...and that is loaded at the beggining of the application.

After that, when we go to the page where I have to show the images, I have this:

```
public BankAndCards()
    {

        createGridView();
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Invoked when this page is about to be displayed in a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e">Event data that describes how this page was reached.
    /// This parameter is typically used to configure the page.</param>
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
    }

    void createGridView()
    {

        QueryPicturesToShow();
    }

    public void QueryPicturesToShow()
    {
        var pics = from medio in GlobalVariables.Medios
                         where medio.id != null
                         select new { Name = medio.name, Id = medio.id, Picture = medio.img};

        foreach (var item in pics)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(item.Name);
            Debug.WriteLine(item.Id);
            Debug.WriteLine(item.Picture);

            savePicToDisk();
        }
    }

    private async void savePicToDisk()
    {
        //what should I do here?
    }
}
```

The data I get, from the API says (in order: name, id, picture)

> Banco Galicia 2 /method/21030342
>
> Bango River 3 /method/210321012

Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: I'd implement a cache of some kind. After you retrieve the JSON and the images, store the images in the cache. When you later need the images retrieve it from the cache. If an image is stale, retrieve it from the source again. Btw, what is the environment you are targeting? WPF, Silverlight, Windows Phone? Please add an appropriate tag to your question.

Comment: WP8.1... sorry I did not tag it

Comment: How is the image serialized in the JSON? Base64?

Comment: Seems like, from JSON, I get the "address" of the picture, to download it / show it in a grid...Here is an example:  http://ec2-52-8-2-140.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/method/2104400

Comment: So, it changes the whole topic: How to download and save a pic from the web and show it in a grid (at least how to download it and save it in an accessible place)

Answer (score 0):

I got it...
For some reason I was not able to see the pics in the folder until I unplugged the phone and plugged in again...

```
public void QueryPicturesToShow()
    {

        var pics = from medio in GlobalVariables.Medios
                   where medio.img != null
                   select new { Name = medio.name, Id = medio.id, Picture = medio.img };

        foreach (var item in pics)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(item.Name);
            Debug.WriteLine(item.Id);
            Debug.WriteLine(item.Picture);



            savePicToDisk(item.Picture, item.Name, item.Id);
        }
    }

                private async void savePicToDisk(string picAddress, string picName, string picId)
                {

                    StorageFolder folder = await KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.CreateFolderAsync("workingFolder", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

                    StorageFile file = await folder.CreateFileAsync((picName + picId + ".png"), CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

                    string url = GlobalVariables.apiUrl + picAddress;


                    Debug.WriteLine(url);
                    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

                    byte[] responseBytes = await client.GetByteArrayAsync(url);

                    var stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);

                    using (var outputStream = stream.GetOutputStreamAt(0))
                    {
                        DataWriter writer = new DataWriter(outputStream);
                        writer.WriteBytes(responseBytes);
                        await writer.StoreAsync();
                        await outputStream.FlushAsync();

                    }
    }
```

So, now, I just need to know how do I bind them to a gridView, so, if anyone knows, you are going to save me a lot of time (I was thinking to put them in a list, but I am not sure if is going to work)

Thanks!